# Calculating Rank at Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have below requirement

[image]

I am using condition like `rank() ( partition by Name order by sum(marks)) as rank`, i am getting the rank value as Rank_Coming column, but i am expecting the value like Rank expected column.

Please suggest how to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rank expect is **not** `GROUP BY Name -- PARTITION BY Name`. It's `ORDER BY Name`

Try this:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, but it is directly jumping to the 3, not showing 2, i need to show two for the next row, 2 is missing at my result

Comment: You use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `RANK()`. I have just fixed my code

Comment: But at my case it should be by marks and name, this code it is giving rank for name by alphabetically irrespective of marks, can you please suggest what to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `SUM` first and then use that in ranking.

```
;WITH CteSum AS(
    SELECT *,
        SumMarks = SUM(Marks) OVER(PARTITION BY Name)
    FROM tbl
),
CteRnk AS(
    SELECT *,
        rnk = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SumMarks DESC)
    FROM CteSum
)
SELECT * FROM CteRnk
```